# fetch in fetch JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, url, fetch

I have a problem with fetching datain JS. I have 2 urls, first look like: "http://somewebsite.com/users", and second url: `http://website.com/details/${user.login}`. I want to merge data from urls and put them into the array. My code doesn't work.

```
async function dataFetch() {
  return await fetch("https://http://somewebsite.com/users")

  .then.forEach(async function(user){
    const resp= await fetch(`http://website.com/details/${user.login}`)
    const respJSON = resp.json();
    user.login= respJSON.json();
  })
  .then(x=>console.log(x))
}
---------------------------
Input:
data from first url:
[
  {"login":"xor","password":"1234"},
  {"login":"Ozark","password":"56789"}
]

data from second url:
[
  {"login":"xor","name":"Capri Cosa", "age": "33"},
  {"login":"Ozark","name":"Marg Arita", "age": "27"}
]
---------------------------

Output:
[
  {"login":"xor","password":"1234","name":"Capri Cosa", "age": "33"},
  {"login":"Ozark","password":"56789","name":"Marg Arita", "age": "27"}
]
```

Comment: Always check the error console. `then` is a method, not a property, and expects a callback as its parameter. You can't just chain a `forEach` to it in the way you have.

Comment: `then.forEach` not sure where you got that from and 
`const respJSON = resp.json();
    user.login= respJSON.json();` makes no sense

Comment: I think what the `respJSON.json()` is for is used after they do `.then(result => result.json())` then chaining another `.then()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for a simpler approach (helper method based on closures)

```
function merger(){
    var data = []
    return function(url){
        return fetch(url).
                then(resp => resp.json()).
                then(resp => (data.push(resp), data))
    }
}
```

This can be used as this:

```
var urlMerge = merger()
urlMerge(<<url1>>).then(console.log)// [{<<first response>>}]
urlMerge(<<url2>>).then(console.log)// [{<<first response>>},{<<second response>>}]
urlMerge(<<url3>>).then(console.log)// [{<<first response>>},{<<second response>>},{<<third response>>}]
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of reasons why the code isn't working. First you can't use `.forEach()` on a `.then()` since `.then()` is a method and not an array type property. Next, when you do `.then()` to use the `.json()` method you need to use it like so:

```
.then(result => result.json())
```

then chaining another then method.

Now for merging the two contents, from my understanding of what you want your output to be, you want the login and passwords in the same object as the age and name which can be done like so:

```
(function dataFetch() {
   let finalArray = [];

   fetch("https://somewebsite.com/users")
     .then(result => result.json())
     .then(result =>{
         fetch("https://somewebsite.com/${user.login}")
           .then(resp => resp.json())
           .then(resp => {
              for(let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                  finalArray.push({login: resp[i].login, name: resp[i].name, password: 
                  result[i].password, age: resp[i].age})
             }
         })

    })
    .then(() => {
       for(let i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
          console.log(finalArray[i]);
       }
   })
})();
```

Hope this helps